# tuple of tuples notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, products

Is the following notation right for indicating a $\mathit{m}-$tuple of  $\mathit{n_{j}}-$tuples (I mean that each tuple of the $\mathit{m}-$tuple has a different number of elements)?

$(((x_{i})_{1\leq i\leq n_{j}})_{j})_{1\leq j\leq m}$

With reference to this post [n-tuple Notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146428/n-tuple-notation) is it possible also to write the following notation?

$\left [ \left [ \left [ x_{i} \right ]_{i=1}^{n_{j}} \right ]_{j} \right ]_{j=1}^{m}$

Is the following notation still the same?

$\left [ \left [ x_{i}^{j} \right ]_{i=1}^{n_{j}} \right ]_{j=1}^{m}$

Are both the above notations with square brackets the same if written with round parenthesis like the following?

$\left ( \left ( \left ( x_{i} \right )_{i=1}^{n_{j}} \right )_{j} \right )_{j=1}^{m}$

$\left ( \left ( x_{i}^{j} \right )_{i=1}^{n_{j}} \right )_{j=1}^{m}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important that the innermost entries (the  ixes) have *two* indices. All proposed notations that don't have this feature are flawed. E.g., it would then not be possible to store your array in a computer and retrieve individual entries at will. Furthermore I'd avoid upper indices (this is a question of taste; in my view they  belong to an out-dated kind of differential geometry), and I'd also restrict the use of square brackets to the case of rectangular matrices, i.e., to the case where all $n_j$ are the same.

So you have a list (or tuple) $L:=({\bf x}_1,{\bf x}_2, \ldots,{\bf x}_m)$  of length $m\geq1$, consisting of tuples
$${\bf x}_j=(x_{j,1},x_{j,2},\ldots, x_{j,n_j})\qquad(1\leq j\leq m)\ ,$$
where the ${\bf x}_j$ have individual lengths $n_j\geq1$. One then would introduce this nested list in the form
$$L=\bigl((x_{j,i})_{1\leq i\leq n_j}\bigr)_{1\leq j\leq m}\ .$$
In this way the ${\bf x}_j$  appear as rows of a pseudomatrix with rows of unequal lengths.